# ¿Cómo crear permisos de usuarios?

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy creando un proyecto en el que se ingresan usuarios llamados empleados y 1 usuario llamado admin. Mi pregunta es sencilla: ¿cómo puedo hacer para que al ingresar el usuario empleado se muestren ciertas cosas y cuando ingrese el admin se muestren otras?

La verdad es que estuve intentando hacerlo y ni lo logré, probé con JavaScript pero me da `null`.

Paso código que hice:

```
 <script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    let usu_per = document.getElementById("usu_permiso");
    let sucu_per = document.getElementById("sucu_permiso");
    let PERmiso = document.getElementById("permiso");

    if (PERmiso == "empleado") {

        usu_per.classList.add("d-none");
        sucu_per.classList.add("d-none");
        
    }else {
    
         usu_per.classList.add("d-block");
        sucu_per.classList.add("d-block");
    }
})
</script>
```

Saco el valor de acá:

```
   <td id="permiso" style="font-size: 20px;"><?php  echo $dato->PERMISO ?></td>
```

Lo que quiero que haga es que, si el permiso es igual a empleado, que a esos botones les agregue un d-none, pero si el usuario es admin, entonces que les agregue d-block. Al hacerlo, el valor PERmiso me trae null y siempre me agrega el b-block.

Comment: Mala idea ocultar o mostrar los campos con JS en una validación de usuario, cualquiera podría simplemente cambiar esas clases desde el front. Ya que estás usando PHP, lee sobre la variable `$_SESSION`  y realiza la misma condicional que ya tienes, pero con PHP. Cuando tengas algo más adelantado, vuelve acá y edita tu pregunta. Revisa [ask]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Gracias a todos, perdón por hacer una pregunta mal :c es mi primera ves jeje.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jheyman, Estube investigando como hacerlo con $_SESSION y lo logre muchas gracias